# Robots.txt got changed to disallow crawling by accident

Tags: robots.txt, google-index

Our *robots.txt* mistakenly got changed to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This occurred about 2 weeks ago and was changed back yesterday to allow crawling.

Our listed pages in the Googles have decreased substantially, though it looks like Google has already started adding more search results for the site in question since changing the *robots.txt* back.

Are there long term repercussions of this happening, or will everything get back to normal once the site is crawled again?

Comment: Status Quo will come back. But not in 24hours, give it time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Google has started adding pages again, then you are fine.  We had this happen with a few sites that were pushed from development into production and their *robots.txt* was not changed.

In fact, unless you are trying to block pages, I recommend removing *robots.txt* completely.  There's no point in saying allow everything in *robots.txt* when that is the default action.

Comment: I never really bought the argument that a robots.txt file should exist even if it is empty. That does not seem to make sense. I am sure that the bots we care about are fault tolerant if this was ever a problem. However, there are always bots to block in my view.

Comment: Also you can add your sitemap file to the robots.txt, which is not bad

Comment: Yea, I've got sitemap in the robots.txt as well. Thanks a bunch for the insight :)

Comment: Make sure sitemaps and robots.txt are in agreement.  I've seen issues where meta info, robots.txt and site maps all told the bots to do different things.

Comment: @closetnoc the main reason is to prevent 404 errors in your error log, since search engines will continue to check for the file.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat With respect. Somehow I think we have a disconnect that is clearly my fault. I was arguing the premise rather than the reality which clearly in retrospect was kind of a silly thing to do. I get your point about 404s but somehow I guess seeing valid 404s has never bothered me. Your point is well taken! Especially since I have always had a robots.txt! It never occurred to me that a 404 would be a consideration for someone. Thanks for pointing that out! BTW- In my defense, I probably did not have enough coffee when I wrote the comment. Plus I am getting old. Any sympathy?

Comment: Meh. People will continue to scan for phpMyAdmin, doesn't mean that I'll put something there just to avoid seeing 404 errors in my logs. I think there are enough good reasons to have a *nearly*-empty robots.txt instead of an empty one. No need to enter into a futile attempt to clean up your server logs :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop Oh yes! I agree! I set up bait for bad accesses- if you saw my log files, you would know that I agree. It just did not occur to me there was another reason someone would want to have an empty robots.txt. Their point of view is valid for their purposes. For me I don't care unless the 404 is for a page that should be there. My site is mostly automated and so 404s rarely exist. I work the site from behind a database. *Do not pay attention to the man behind the curtain!* The Wizzard of Oz

Comment: @Steve yes that is true, but from my experience robots.txt is requested much more. May as well cut down on the easy 404s.